# To use JSP and PHP in the same application

Tags: php, apache, jsp, tomcat

My application is based on `PHP`. Now I want to integrate a web-reporter which is written in `JSP`. So, I have an `Apache HTTP Server` and an application written in PHP. I even installed `Tomcat` to serve `JSP` files and it is running well at 8080 port. I also got mod_jk.so and added a line `LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so` to `httpd.conf` file, but still I can't run `JSP` files from my application folders (port 80). I guess, there should be extra tuning of `httpd.conf` file, but I do not know, what exactly should be done.

**EDIT**
My `workers.properties` looks exactly like this

```
JkWorkerProperty worker.list=ajp13w
JkWorkerProperty worker.ajp13w.type=ajp13
JkWorkerProperty worker.ajp13w.host=localhost
JkWorkerProperty worker.ajp13w.port=8009
```

My `uriworkermap.properties` looks like this

```
/jsp/*=ajp13w
```

where `jsp` is a folder in htdocs, containing jsp files

And finally, my `httpd.conf` now contains

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

#AddModule     mod_jk.c
#JkWorkersFile C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/conf/workers.properties
#JkMountFile   C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/conf/uriworkermap.properties
JkLogFile     C:/Apache/logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
```

Each commented line makes it impossible to start the server.

**EDIT**

I installed a newer version of Tomcat - Tomcat 8.0, but the problem remains unsolved.

**EDIT**

Judging by this link [apache.org](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200902.mbox/%3Cc09599f40902270431q7269aa15h6550a3c0e979dba8@mail.gmail.com%3E), the problem can be solved by changing `server.xml` (of tomcat) and some changes of httpd.conf (concerning virtual host). But as allways in this world, this article does not provide any concrete examples.

**EDIT**

I moved one step ahead. The most stupid error which made it impossible to run the server was quotes. So this line in `httpd.conf` - `JkWorkersFile C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/conf/workers.properties` gave me an error, but after three hours of struggle it turned out, that it should be `JkWorkersFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/conf/workers.properties"`. So, now it runs. However, when I go to `localhost/jsp/index.jsp` I now see an **`Apache Tomcat error report`: `HTTP Status 404 - /jsp/index.jsp`**. This seems to be the last error, but still I do not know how to deel with it.

**EDIT**

Now I see it works. Though, I get an unexpected behaviour. I thought I could place `JSP` files inside htdocs folder, but as it turned out, they should be placed inside tomcat.

Comment: Did you create the config files for mod_jk to specify for it which Tomcat applications to expose to port 80? I.e. adding JkWorkersFile to httpd.conf and creating that file. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html

Comment: No, I did not. By the way, I found these links http://rimuhosting.com/mod_jk2_and_mod_proxy_ajp.jsp and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html which seem to be promissing, but I still can't understand what modifications should be done, since I never delt with reverse proxy and all that stuff.

Comment: The documentation here is much clearer. http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

Comment: Thanks! But there are tons of information and terminology (workers etc.).

Comment: And as allways, the documentation is outdated. It says, for example, about workers.properties file in conf. But I see that there is no workers.properties file, instead there are catalina.properties and logging.properties. It really drives me crazy, when documentation has no sense at all

Comment: You have to create the workers.properties and uriworkermap.properties files yourself. They don't come with the Tomcat installation. workers.properties defines a worker, sort of like a thread to handle the requests. uriworkermap.properties defines what applications in Tomcat are exposed to HTTPD and what worker handles them.

Comment: The documentation is rather vague and boring. It says, for example, that port directive is "Port number of the remote Tomcat instance listening for defined protocol requests", and then it says about ports 8009 and 8011. But how these ports relate to my apache port 80 and to my tomcat port 8080 - I do not understand. And I can't understand, should I specify AJP13 or AJP14. The worst of all, the documentation does not provide even the simplest example. It speaks too much, but it does nothing.

Comment: It should not point to the folder but to the context served by tomcat. DO you have a jsp context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For minimal setup.

workers.properties file example:

```
# Minimal jk configuration
JkWorkerProperty worker.list=ajp13w
JkWorkerProperty worker.ajp13w.type=ajp13
JkWorkerProperty worker.ajp13w.host=localhost
JkWorkerProperty worker.ajp13w.port=8009
```

8009 is the default port mod_jk uses to communicate between HTTPD and Tomcat when it forwards requests to Tomcat. If you change it here you have to change it in Tomcat's server.xml too.

uriworkermap.properties file example:

```
/my_tomcat_app_to_expose_to_httpd/*=ajp13w
```

The * there is a file extension filter. * for all files, *.jsp for just jsp files, etc.

Any app listed here will be made available via HTTPD.

In httpd.conf you need:

```
LoadModule    jk_module  libexec/mod_jk.so
AddModule     mod_jk.c
JkWorkersFile /config_location/workers.properties
JkMountFile   /config_location/uriworkermap.properties
JkLogFile     /log_location/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
```

Comment: I checked. Unfortunatelly, it does not help. AddModule,  JkWorkersFile and JkMountFile specifying results in an error

Comment: You may need to download the newer version, and use the download for Tomcat connector rather than and older mod_jk version as JkMountFile is a newer directive.

Comment: You mean a newer version of Tomcat? And what do you mean by Tomcat connector? Do you mean this - http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache//tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/. I downloaded an archive and see tons of files there. What to do with all this hell - I do not know.